# Excel - How can I convert two columns into a grid of matches?

Tags: excel

How can I take two columns with repeated data and create a grid that shows when the value in A matches the value in B in the same row?  In the example at the end, how do take columns A,B and create the grid in Columns D-H?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with PivotTable:
(Tested on MS Office 2016)

Data:

[image: Data]

Steps:-

1. Select The Data including the header.
2. Goto Insert -> Pivot Table.
3. Drag Student to `Rows` and Color to `Columns` and `Values` in PivotTable fields dialog.
4. Select the `PivotTable` and click `Options` in `Analyse` tab `PivotTable` section.
5. In `Totals & Filters` tab, unmark `Show grand total for rows` and `Show grand total for columns`.
6. In `Display` tab, unmark `Display Field Captions and filter drop downs`.
7. Select all the Count of Colors and goto `Analyse` tab `Field Settings`.
8. Select Summarize Value by `Count` and click `Number Format`.
9. Select `Custom` and Type **X** in `Type`.

Output of Step 3:-

[image: Output of Step 3]

Output after Step 6:-

[image: Output after Step 6]

Output after Step 9:-

[image: Output after Step 9]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your data is precisely as laid out in your image. You can use this formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(CONCATENATE($D2,E$1),CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10),0))),"X", "")
```

1. In cell `E2` add the formula.
2. Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`
3. Drag the formula over the remaining cells